# Unit Of Work, ILifetimeScope, & Autofac Container

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a project that implements the Unit Of Work.  Typically I execute the unit of work utilizing a *using* statement.  Reading the Autofac documentation, it says to *"create a child lifetime scope from the the container and resolve from that"*.  In the class that I want to use my unit of work, do I use constructor injection to inject an *ILifetimeScope* so I can create my child lifetime scope?

```
    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var uow = scope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();

        // do something

        uow.Complete();
    }
```

## Autofac Documentation

[Autofac Execution Section](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html#application-execution)

> During application execution, you will need to make use of the components you registered. You do this by resolving them from a lifetime scope.
>
> The container itself is a lifetime scope, and you can technically just resolve things right from the container. It is not recommended to resolve from the container directly, however.
>
> When you resolve a component, depending on the instance scope you define, a new instance of the object gets created. (Resolving a component is roughly equivalent to calling “new” to instantiate a class. That’s really, really oversimplifying it, but from an analogy perspective it’s fine.) Some components may need to be disposed (like they implement IDisposable) - Autofac can handle disposing those components for you when the lifetime scope is disposed.
>
> However, the container lives for the lifetime of your application. If you resolve a lot of stuff directly from the container, you may end up with a lot of things hanging around waiting to be disposed. That’s not good (and you may see a “memory leak” doing that).
>
> Instead, create a child lifetime scope from the container and resolve from that. When you’re done resolving components, dispose of the child scope and everything gets cleaned up for you.

### Example from Autofac Documentation

```
    namespace DemoApp
    {
      public class Program
      {
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          // ...the stuff you saw earlier...
        }

        public static void WriteDate()
        {
          // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
          // use it, then dispose of the scope.
          using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
          {
            var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();
            writer.WriteDate();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

## Update based on comments below

This is a web application (MVC) I’m building for learning purposes.  I will running my Unit of Work from my service layer.  Please let me know if this is incorrect approach but that’s how I’ve seen some others do it.  I believe it runs in a request but how would I be able to check? Debugging?  I don’t know why it needs to be isolated.  I just was reading the Autofac documentation and they recommend, at least in the execution section, to not resolve from the root but please tell me if you feel differently.  I’m learning so any insight you have I would love to hear it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @IndyCodeNoob, welcome to StackOverflow! We need more details about your app to be able to give proper guidance. Is it a web app? a console application? a desktop application? Depending on the type, you might (not) need to create a lifetime scope yourself.

Comment: Hi Mickaël.  It’s a web (mvc) app.

Comment: Have you [checked out the Autofac docs on MVC integration?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) You get a per-request lifetime scope for free. If that's not enough, you can create child scopes from the request scope if needed, but 90% of the time, per-request does the trick. If that won't work, we'll definitely need more info here. Where are you starting the unit of work? Does it run in a request or in a background thread? Why does it need to be isolated from the request? (Update your question rather than responding in comments if possible - makes it easier to see.)